# logstash add_field and remove_field

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm attempting to simplify my logstash config. I want to split the program field into separate fields (as show below) however I would prefer to use just one grok statement (if it's at all possible!)

Of the two examples below I get an _grokparsefailure  on the second example, but not the first. Since grok has the add_field and remove_field options I would assume that I could combine it all into one grok statement. Why is this not the case? Have I missed some ordering/syntax somewhere?

Sample log:

```
2016-02-16T16:42:06Z ubuntu docker/THISTESTNAME[892]: 172.16.229.1 - - [16/Feb/2016:16:42:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Why does this work:

```
filter {

       # Extracts the docker name, ID, image etc elements
       mutate {
               add_field => { "[@metadata][program]" => "%{program}" }
               remove_field => "[program]"
       }

       grok {
                patterns_dir => "/logstash/patterns_dir/docker"
                match => { "[@metadata][program]" => "%{D_ID}" }
       }

}
```

But this does not:

```
filter {

        grok {
               add_field => { "[@metadata][program]" => "%{program}" }
               remove_field => "[program]"
               patterns_dir => "/logstash/patterns_dir/docker"
               match => { "[@metadata][program]" => "%{D_ID}" }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add_field and remove_field only run if the underlying filter works.  In your second example, the [@metadata][program] doesn't yet exist for you to run grok{} against.

Comment: Huh, so in a way if I insisted on doing it that way and only using grok the way it could logically be done would be (even though the first gork returns an error as there were no matches):

        grok {
               add_field => { "[@metadata][program]" => "%{program}" }
               remove_field => "[program]"
        }

////        grok {
               patterns_dir => "/logstash/patterns_dir/docker"
               match => { "[@metadata][program]" => "%{D_ID}" }
        }

Comment: Using mutate to add the field and then using grok is fine, and is a better understood syntax than using grok to just run the add_field and remove_field.

Answer (score 0):

This was directly answered by @Alan, however I found this way a little more readable and compressed my code even more:

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => "/logstash/patterns_dir/docker-patterns"
    match => { "program" => "%{D_ID}" }
    overwrite => [ "program" ]
}
```